# Server side error processing in Ember 1.13.3

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, json-api

What is the right way to work with server side errors in Ember 1.13.3?

I'm using RESTAdapter and I tried it with/without this code:

```
handleResponse: function(status, headers, payload) {
if (payload.errors) {
  return new DS.InvalidError(payload.errors);
}
return this._super(...arguments);
```

}

My server returns 422 with such JSON:

```
            {
                errors: [
                    {
                        source: {pointer: 'data'},
                        detail: 'Not saved'
                    }
                ]
            }
```

In my route I'm saving the model in such way:

```
job.save().then(function() {
    console.log('OK');
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Error: ', err, ' Model ', job.get('isError'));
  });
```

In case of error the flow comes to catch block and 'err' is InvalidError object as expected but job.get('isError') returns false.

And right now I don't know how to get errors in component UI since model property isError is always false.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the point of [`isError`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#property_isError)

> If true the adapter reported that it was unable to save local changes to the backend for any reason other than a server-side validation error.

What you should be checking is [`isValid`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#property_isValid)

> A record will be in the valid state when the adapter did not report any server-side validation failures.

Comment: You're right. Thanks. Using 'pointer: 'data'' in error I want to tell that it's global error not just property. But how can I get this error from model? If I use "pointer: 'data/attributes/name'" then it's not a problem to call mode.get('errors').get('name').

Comment: The answer to the question in the comment is hidden in the posted answer. If it's not a validation error but other, the response should come with different error status code, for eg. 400 (bad request). In that case, error can be handled in promise's error callback. Usually parsing `responseText` to get the error.